# Автонумерация строк в ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `ListBox`. WinForm. В него добавляются / удаляются записи. В качестве источника данных использую `List<string> QuestionsList`;
`lbAnswers.DataSource = QuestionsList`;

Как в этой ситуации сделать автонумерация строк вот такого характера. Т.е при выводе добавить префикс в виде номера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может событие какое или нужно наследоваться от него и пилить свою логику для добавления записай или может есть другие варианты?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov WinForms

Answer (score 2):

Нашел событие Format и мне это подходит

```
private void lbAnswers_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            Question ques = e.ListItem as Question;
            if (ques != null)
            {
                var items = (sender as ListControl).DataSource as IList<Question>;
                if (items != null)
                    e.Value = items.IndexOf(ques) + 1 + ". " + ques.Text;
            }
        }
```